# Are there any non-trivial solutions of $a^n = b^m + 1$ for natural $a$, $b$ and $n, m \ge 2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponentiation

There is an obvious solution $3^2 = 2^3 + 1$.

However, I tried to search for solutions in the range $a, b \in [2,100]$ and $\min(n,m) \in [2,1000]$, but did not find any.

It is easy to show that $a$ and $b$ have to be co-prime, but I couldn't advance anywhere further.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture ... It has been recently proved.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure it is a known problem. I should have directly asked ChatGPT. Indeed, it knows about Catalan's conjecture and knows about Mihăilescu's theorem, but still says that this is an open question :)

Comment: Maybe I can add how I arrived at this problem. I was thinking whether it is possible to approximate $10^n$ with $2^m$ better than $2.4\%$ of $1024$. Indeed it is possible and the relative difference eventually decreases when $n$ grows to infinity.

Comment: Do not use ChatGPT ! It does not derserve a single user !

Comment: There is a similar conjecture (Pillai's conjecture) that for every difference there are onyly finite many pairs of perfect powers having this difference , but the only actually solved case is difference $1$ , where $(8/9)$ is the only solution.